# white space occur in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I am trying to update query using php and database and display the textarea in a page. Here is my code,problem is i get the text area with some whitespace. Please help.

```
if (isset($_POST["events"])&&isset($_POST["description"]))
{
    $id=$_POST["id"];
    $title=$_POST["events"];
    $description=$_POST["description"];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="hotel1_galery_eventedit.php" method="post" class="col-sm-4" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $val->event_id;?>">
    <div class="form-group has-info">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Event title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="events" value="<?php echo $val->event_title;?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-info">
        <label class="control-label" >Event Description</label>
    <textarea name="description" class="form-control text-left" rows="3">
    <?php echo $val->event_description;?>
    </textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: May be line breaks are adding space..

Comment: `<textarea name="description" class="form-control text-left" rows="3"><?php echo trim($val->event_description);?></textarea>` if it still produce space then there will be `&nbsp` or `<br>` in `$val->event_description`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `trim()` function. use like this

```
<textarea name="description" class="form-control text-left" rows="3">
<?php echo trim($val->event_description);?>
</textarea>
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your textarea code in same line, the enter inside text area is causing this issue.

```
<textarea name="description" class="form-control text-left" rows="3"><?php echo $val->event_description;?></textarea>
```

The enter which you have added before echoing the value is the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST["events"])&&isset($_POST["description"])) 
            {
                $id=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["id"])); 
                $title=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["events"]));
                $description=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["description"]));
              }
```

It's a secure method to protect our db from unexpected problems and you can also show data without any extra space...

Answer (score 0):

use `trim()`;

```
if (isset($_POST["events"])&&isset($_POST["description"])) 
                {
                    $id=$_POST["id"]; 
                    $title=trim($_POST["events"]);
                    $description= trim($_POST["description"]);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trim() with conditions, if value will be blank in text area then it will be treated as NULL or you can use ''

```
if(isset($_POST["events"])&&isset($_POST["description"])){
            $id=$_POST["id"]; 
            $title=$_POST["events"];
            $description= ($_POST["description"] == '') ? NULL : trim($_POST["description"]);
    }
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Thanks Drenmi to sharing the information about stack rules.